# Session timeout in ASP.NET page added in MVC project for rendering SSRS report

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have developed ASP.NET MVC application with angular. Later stage I found that my company is using SSRS based reporting solution for all the report requirement, hence I have added one .aspx page to show these reports using report viewer control.

The problem here is that, I want to check if Session has expired in .aspx page and call MVC's logout action method and redirect users to MVC's login action method.

Please help on how I can achieve this?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for this suggestion, I tried by adding this code snippet, but the issue is when session got timeout I want my aspx page automatically call Logout method from controller and later I want same aspx page should redirect to login page?

I added this scenario to automatically call to Logout controller method using aspx page's OnPreRender(EventArgs e) and added below code snippet inside

```
protected void base.OnPreRender(e){
    Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
    String.Format("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='{0};url={1}'>",
    Session.Timeout * 60, "/main.mvc/logout?random=report")));
}
```

It is calling Logout method like in above code, but the later on I am getting error page with status something like "The report execution mt1vqsixnjiff145dvbe1o55 has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)". Rather this yellow error page I want to redirect user to Login controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the Session object exists in your page, if you're setting username in your session, it will be null, when session has expired. :

```
if (Session["UserName"] != null)
{
   // Session has not expired
}
else
{
    // Redirect To login since session expired
}
```

You can increase the time out value in minutes using the timeout attribute of sessionState element in web.config.

By default ASP.NET uses cookies to identify which requests belong to a particular session. If cookies are not available, a session can be tracked by adding a session identifier to the URL. To disable cookies, set sessionState cookieless="true".

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
```

Comment: Please find my comment below, as comment section is not allowed me to write more than 600 characters :)